# How to send list of Long to rest controller Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I need to send list of Long objects from Angular to Rest controller in Spring boot :

```
@PostMapping("/accept-friends")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> acceptFriendRequests(@RequestBody List<Long> friendRequestsIds)
```

Is this possible ?

Comment: You want to use GET or POST/PUT methods?

Comment: Post sorry, forget to add

Comment: Create a new bean and add a list field to that bean and map that bean

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36530255/2653420)

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible and will work fine.

```
@PostMapping("/accept-friends")
public ResponseEntity<?> acceptFriendRequests(@RequestBody List<Long> friendRequestsIds) {
  return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have code in Angular 6:

```
getData(friendRequestsIds: number[]) {
    return this.http.post<Question>('/accept-friends', friendRequestsIds);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this:

```
@PostMapping("/listData")
public ResponseEntity<Object> listData(@RequestBody List<?> completeList) {
  return new ResponseEntity<Object>(HttpStatus.OK)
}
```

As I know, you can't keep the `ResponseEntity<void>`

I hope this will help.